# How do I use three HDC's together

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to be able to print things to two hdcs, say `hdcBuf` and `hdcBuf2`. Then I want to `BitBlt` `hdcBuf` onto `hdcBuf2`, and then `BitBlt` `hdcBuf2` onto `hdc`, which is the client window. Here's the code I have now:

```
hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

hdcBuf2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
hbmBackBM2 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, client.right, client.bottom);
hbmOldBackBM2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBuf2, hbmBackBM2);

hdcBuf = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcBuf2); 
hbmBackBM = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcBuf2, client.right, client.bottom);
hbmOldBackBM = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBuf, hbmBackBM);
Graphics g(hdcBuf);
Graphics g2(hdcBuf2);
//drawing stuff with both g and g2
BitBlt(hdcBuf2,0,0,client.right,client.bottom,hdcBuf,0,0,SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdc,0,0,client.right,client.bottom,hdcBuf2,0,0,SRCCOPY);
```

All of the HDCs and HBITMAPs are global, and destroyed properly in WM_DESTROY, and the Graphics objects are GDI+

The reason I need all these hdcs is that I need print things simultaneously with one object on top of another. I have a tiled map, and I loop through a part of it when drawing. I need to print the tiles, and objects which may be on multiple tiles, but the tiles must be under the objects. With just one hdcBuf, I'd need to loop through the map twice to do this.

Right now, my code prints only the contents of `hdcBuf`, the objects on the tiles.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`BitBlt` overwrites the contents of the target device context with the supplied device context. (Or rather, the contents inside the area defined by the parameters) It doesn't try to "mix" the two contexts together. So in your first call to `BitBlt`, you draw the contents of `hdcBuf` over `hdcBuf2` (destroying its contents), and then you draw `hdcBuf2` over `hdc` (also destroying its contents).

You need to loop through the map twice to do this. Keep in mind your example has two loops as well -- they're just inside `BitBlt`.

Answer (score 0):

To mix two sources together you'll want the [AlphaBlend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It is used pretty much like StretchBlt (related to BitBlt, but with an option to resize if you don't use the same size in source and destination). You will have to pass a [BLENDFUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd183393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as parameter for HOW to blend - constantalpha is the simplest method.